# Minecraft armor attributed modifier

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a custom server with attribute modified armor. They only thing I’m concerned about is that the armor modified never seems to get stronger after it adds up to 25. Can someone explain if there is a cap and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Can you give an example of what commands you used?

Comment: I’m on my phone but the the tag I’m doing is AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:”generic.armor”,Amount:14,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:1097,UUIDMost:1098}

Comment: I’m also using the /give command and all the UUIDs have different numbers

Comment: I would give this as an answer except for the fact that there may be a way of getting around this cap that I'm not aware of.

Giving the player the resistance potion effect, or additional hearts of health should have a similar effect in "increasing" the amount of damage a player can take before dying. Extra hearts also has the advantage of being more visibly accurate to the player.

If this doesn't work for you, give some more context and we can try to help you find alternatives

Comment: I’m so confused but I updated my server from 1.11 to 1.13 and it fixed. I’m so confused